# Convert nested list (2d list) to one list of elements using built-in methods like map() in Dart

Tags: dart, data-structures

How can I convert 2d list to 1d list with all the elements in dart?

I have this 2d List:

```dart
List<List<int>> list2d = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
```

What I want is:

```dart
List<int> list1d = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

By converting the first one (2d) to the second (1d) but without writing any (for/while) loops code, if there any built-in methods like `map()/where()/cast()/...etc`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

As other have pointed out, `expand` does what you want

```dart
var list2d = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
var list1d = list2d.expand((x) => x).toList();
```

You can also, and perhaps preferably, use a list literal:

```dart
var list1d = [for (var list in list2d) ...list];
```

In general, `iterable.expand((x) => e).toList()` is equivalent to `[for (var x in iterable) ...e]`.

Comment: I'd rather to use the expand method sometimes for short code, but since we should do care about code readability.. so I may use the spread operator with for loop inside the square braces or just clean for loop only to be more precisely. GREAT WORK THO!

Comment: Thanks! How could you reverse this? Ie. Split a 1D list back into a 2D list every (lets say) 4 items?

Answer (score 1):

Simply by using the `reduce` function like this:

```dart
List<int> list1d = list2d.reduce((value, element) {
    value.addAll(element);
    return value;
});
```

Definition:

```dart
List<T> reduce(List<T> Function(List<T>, List<T>) combine);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `.expand` method:

```dart
List<int> list1d = list2d.expand((e) => e).toList();
```